# ASP MVC basic AJAX Json request returns null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have an MVC application with a controller named Angular (I use AngularJS as well), which has an action called GetQuestion. That action returns a JsonResult which looks like this (grabbed from Chrome):

```
{"game":{"Title":"Diablo III","ImgPaths":["d31.jpg","d32.jpg"]},"Answers":["Diablo III","World of Tanks","Need for Speed"]}
```

My JS function is like this:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: "/Angular/GetQuestion",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "post",
    success: (function (data) { alert(data); })
});
```

But instead of the Json I wrote above, alert window only says [object Object]

### Update

Ok, that was fixed, thaks. However as you may suspect, my goal is not to present this data in alert box, but use it somehow. So here's my controller in Angular

function QuestionCtrl($scope) {

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: "/Angular/GetQuestion",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "post",
    success: function (data) {
        $scope.answers = JSON.stringify(data.Answers);
        $scope.imgPath = JSON.stringify(data.game.ImgPaths[0]);
    }
});

}
```

And then the view:

```
<div ng-controller="QuestionCtrl">

<img class="quizImage" src="~/Gallery/{{imgPath}}"/>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Answer", "Angular", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <p ng-repeat="answer in answers"><input type="radio" name="game"  value="{{answer}}"/> {{answer}}</p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Answer"/></p>
}
</div>
```

And I don't have neither image or the questions. If I hardcode them in controller then it's ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alert will show that, i would suggest using console.log(data)

```
var request = $.ajax({
url: "/Angular/GetQuestion",
dataType: "json",
type: "post",
success: (function (data) { console.log(data); })
 });
```

or as the comments states:

```
var request = $.ajax({
url: "/Angular/GetQuestion",
dataType: "json",
type: "post",
success: (function (data) { alert(JSON.stringify(data)); })
 });
```

Comment: Or, if no console is avail, or for some reason he just **wants** to use alert, he can always do `alert(JSON.stringify(data));`. Though, what browser doesn't have console today?

Answer (score 2):

I resolved my second problem like this:

```
function QuestionCtrl($scope, $http) {

$http.post('/Angular/GetQuestion',null).success(function(data) {
    $scope.answers = data.Answers;
    $scope.imgPath = data.game.ImgPaths[0];
    //console.log($scope.answers);
    //console.log($scope.imgPath);
});
```

}

Note that it's AngularJS.

Comment: See my answer for a way to fix your image source issues.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's happening is because JSON is an Object in JavaScript. When you type

```
alert(data);
```

It will attempt to cast the object to a string which in this case will only output that fact that it's an Object.

To view the contents of an object you can write a simple function to use with an alert or console.log.

```
function outputProperties(anObject) {
    var props = '';
    for (var prop in anObject) {
        props += '\n' + prop + ' value: ' + anObject[prop];
    }
    return props;
}
```

And use it like this

```
alert(outputProperties(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters... when ever you are dynamically building the src url for an image (using the {{expression}} syntax from Angular) you need to not use the "src" attribute and use the "ng-src" angular directive. It allows angular time to process your url before the image is loaded.